# How can I customize display of type names in Sphinx output?

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx

I am using Sphinx to generate documentation for a Python module. Various functions in the module have type annotations. However, I would like to display some types differently for ease of reading. For instance, instead of `Optional[T]`, I would like to display `T?`.

I tried monkeypatching `typing._GenericAlias.__repr__` as a proof of concept, but there was no change in the output, so it seems that Sphinx is doing something special. Is there any way to customize the way that Sphinx displays types?

Comment: As a sanity check, did you `make clean` to remove any previously written HTML files? Sphinx will update from reST source files that have changed, but I am not certain about whether monkeypatching will have an effect. You can also check the timestamp of an HTML file.

Comment: Yes, I made sure that Sphinx was rebuilding the files.

Comment: @ThomSmith I don't want to leave you without my 2 cents on this. I haven't tried such customizing, but from experience the HTML theme you use can render the types differently depending if they lead to their own page, or if they're in an argument list or not. It really depends on the theme and the placing, you can exert some control using the inline cross-reference `'something<else>'` if need be. But, since your HTML theme will take control of the rendering I don't see how to get a "one size fits all" answer for this, that doesn't depend on context, CSS, and has to fiddle with several things...